# How to inject a Spring bean id into another Spring Configured Bean?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I want to be able to pass a bean ID into another bean by reference. So if I have this:

```
<bean id="specialName" class="my.SpecialBean"/>
<bean id="referenceBean" class="my.ReferenceBean">
    <property name="refId" value="<specialName.name>"/>
</bean>
```

---

```
public class ReferenceBean {

    // The spring injected value of this should be 'specialName'        
    public String refId;

    // getter & setter for refId
}
```

The reason I need this, it that ReferenceBean is actually a route builder in Camel and it directs messages to SpecialBean through the Spring Registry. I'm new to Spring and Camel, so if this is an ill conceived questions, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring-EL -

```
<bean id="specialName" class="my.SpecialBean"/>
<bean id="referenceBean" class="my.ReferenceBean">
    <property name="refId" value="#{specialName.name}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'd just found this myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I try to do this, I get an org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 13): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on object of type (...)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just put the id statically into refId there? It will not change later so why should you do something complicated here?

```
<bean id="specialName" class="my.SpecialBean"/>
<bean id="referenceBean" class="my.ReferenceBean">
    <property name="refId" value="specialName"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Your suggesting was my initial approach. I liked it because it is simple and clear. However, I when I change a bean ID, I don't want to risk forgetting to update the ReferenceBean. An ideal solution would cause Spring xml to fail validation. A less ideal solution would cause Spring to fail on startup. The solution you've given will only fail once the Camel Route is traversed.

Comment: Ok .. if you want spring to fail if you change one of the two then the above solution from Biju is better.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<bean id="specialName" class="my.SpecialBean" />
<bean id="referenceBean" class="my.ReferenceBean">
    <property name="refId" ref="specialName" />
</bean>
```

This way your bean should be injected (provided you change the String attribute in my.SpecialBean.

Then you can get any attribute you want.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in my circumstance. I get an exception with text like this: BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'referenceBean' ... Failed to convert property value of type 'my.SpecialBean' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'refId'. I think the problem is that the type of refId is String but I'm assigning an object of type my.SpecialBean.

Comment: Yep, that's what `provided you change the String attribute in my.SpecialBean` stood for ^^

Comment: I understand that injecting the bean does not make sense if you want to use the bean id in the camel route. So why not simply inject the bean id like I proposed above?

Comment: What you answered is exactly what Spina needed and needs to do here. I was suggesting another road and explaining in my last comment why it didn't work for him :)

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion now. I'm hesitant to change the type of refId. The Camel route invokes a method on the SpecialBean using reflection. To do this, it needs to know the registry name for the bean and the name of the method to invoke. In fact, I don't believe this solution will work because it doesn't actually supply the registry name to ReferenceBean (which is required for the reflection to work.) I'm I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: You can inject the whole bean reference and call any method you want on it. But then you have to change refId type from String to SpecialBean (and change the property name by the way).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `idref` element (see [Spring XML Beans Schema](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/resources/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd#L811-L834)):

```
<bean id="specialName" class="my.SpecialBean"/>
<bean id="referenceBean" class="my.ReferenceBean">
    <property name="refId">
        <idref bean="specialName"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```